# How to make a bigger array list in android?

Tags: android, arraylist

I want to display in a list like 80 items but after 10 when i made a test the application stops and the logcat says ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

How can i make my list much more bigger?

My code:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.galerie_galerie);

        rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
            RowItem item = new RowItem(images[i], titles[i], descriptions[i]);
            rowItems.add(item);
        }

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,
                R.layout.list_item, rowItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting this error because either your `image`s or `descriptions` array isn't as large as your `titles` array.

For example, If:

- Your `titles` array has 10 elements
- Your `images` array has 10 elements
- Your `description` has 9 elements

When you try and access that 10th element in your for loop, you pull out the 10th element from titles and images, but description doesn't have that many elements so you'll get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

How you avoid this happening will depend entirely on your data and what result you want. If you have the data to support an image and description for every title, then you may have just made a mistake while initializing your data. That could be an easy fix.

If you don't have the data to support an image and/or description for every title, you should do a check inside your `for` loop to see if there is an image or description available for the title. If there isn't (the current index you're checking is passed the length of the array), then you could just throw a place holder in to the `ArrayList`. If you do that, remember to handle it later when you're actually using that it.

Comment: Or may be something is wrong with his `CustomListViewAdapter` !

Comment: @user2152480 Glad to hear it!